# rabbitMQ Configuration file missing

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using Rabbitmq 3.7.2 and Erlang 20.2 , and bydefualt RMQ config file missing 
in following path C:\Users\vxadmin\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\config

based on references following step i took -

1 Created environment variable

RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE    C:\Users\vxadmin\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\config

2  Open command prompt as Admin

and run rabbitmq-service.bat remove 
but its throw the error 
"C:\Users\vxadmin\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\config"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

anyone Please guide me what else i have to setup to get config file for RMQ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to set that environment variable. Assuming that the `vxadmin` user installed RabbitMQ, if you'd like to create a config file do the following:

- Unset the `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable
- Open the "RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)" start menu item
- Run the following commands:

  .\rabbitmq-service.bat stop

  .\rabbitmq-service.bat remove
- Create the following file `C:\Users\vxadmin\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.conf` containing the configuration you'd like. NOTE: this file is in the "ini-style" format. Please use the correct format - it is well-documented [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)
- Run the following commands in the previous shell:

  .\rabbitmq-service.bat install

  .\rabbitmq-service.bat start

Comment: hi yes i able to load config file , was doing 2 mistake   , 1 - i thought just need add env variable and file will copy automatic .   2 - file need save with .config extension now able to load config file . thanks