# Set relative memory usage

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq, windows-server, memory-limit

We have a RabbitMQ service (v3.7.12), on a Windows Server 2016 machine, that needs more than the default relative memory setting of 40% (vm_memory_high_watermark = 0.4).

By default RabbitMQ has no RabbitMQ.conf file, and uses default settings. I downloaded an example config file from [GitHub](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example).
In the config file I uncommented `vm_memory_high_watermark = 0.4` and changed it to `vm_memory_high_watermark = 0.8`.
I saved the file to c:\somelocation\RabbitMQ.conf and added a system environment variable `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` with the aforementioned location as the value.

I rebooted the machine and checked whether the config values have been picked up by opening a cmd prompt and running: `rabbitmqctl.bat environment > c:\settings.txt`. After opening the file, with a decent editor that can format the settings, I found that the memory setting is still set to 0.4.

I also tried to put the file in the folders, as I think these are the roaming folders for the system account:

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\RabbitMQ

Also tried this answer:
[Remove and reinstall the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123148/rabbitmq-configuration-file-missing)

What do I need to do to have RabbitMQ pick up my custom memory setting?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by setting the variable via:

```
rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0.8
```

And then executing the steps to remove and reinstall the server as mentioned in my question.